# Unexpected error calling class

Tags: php

I use the below code

```
echo "Start";
class A extends B
{
   //stuff
}

abstract class B extends C
{
   //stuff
}

abstract class C
{
   //stuff
}
echo "end";
```

When I run this page it doesn't shows any error but it not executed. "Start" is echoed but "end" is not echoed. Can anyone please explain where I am doing wrong? It's really needed.

Comment: What do your error logs say?

Comment: turn on display_errors and error_reporting. never debug in the dark.

Comment: It doesn't show any error...

Comment: show errors please [http://codepad.viper-7.com/06ScVN](http://codepad.viper-7.com/06ScVN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Class `B` not found" - this is the error I got.

this works:

```
echo "Start";

abstract class B extends C
{
    //stuff
}

abstract class A extends B
{
    //stuff
}

abstract class C
{
    //stuff
}
echo "end";
```

Comment: What the...?!? If there was any sense in PHP, you should (consistent to the first problem) get a *Class C not found* error, but you don't...

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: yes, I know that it is very strange. I have no idea why this happens, but class `C` is found:) Furthermore: if `B` doesn't extend `C` and classes are declared in TS's order - it also works fine.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois: class `C` not found if I make it extened from another class `D` :D metaphysics...

Comment: :-) So the php parser treats classes differently whether or not they are extending something.

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois seems so